# Why replaceFirst and replaceAll give different results?

Tags: java, regex

The following code will set str to "testss"

```
String str = "test".replaceAll("(.*)$","$1s");
```

Where as the following code will set it to "tests"

```
String str = "test".replaceFirst("(.*)$","$1s");
```

I would have expected both operations to produce the same result. Can someone explain why replaceAll adds an extra s to the end of the string?

Comment: Try doing this `"(.*$)"` and what do you get?

Comment: Replace with `"[$1]"` instead - that should give some hints :)

Comment: hmm... (.*$) didn't help, but [$1] gave me "[test]s[]s". So there is an empty capture. Why?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Without the s in there, notice the output is `[test][]` - what does this say about the captures? Now, compare with `(.+)$` as the regex; what changed?

Comment: @pst - wow, thanks. That is the first time I've seen a different using + instead of *. Can you explain why?

Comment: The `+` modifier means match *one* or more. `*` is *zero* or more.

Comment: ah, and the light goes on. thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `"(.*)$"` captures two strings from `"test"`, `"test"` and the empty string (""). So replaceAll will add two `"s"`.

Comment: thanks Mat. You say "empty string" to which one are you referring?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini `[test][]` <-- the 2nd capture was the "empty string"